# Error with git commits: 'gpg-agent' is older than us (2.0.30 < 2.1.20)

Tags: git, gnupg

How would I go about fixing this?

```
gpg: WARNING: server 'gpg-agent' is older than us (2.0.30 < 2.1.20)
```

Comment: Looks like `brew reinstall gpg-agent` may have resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

Version 2.0.30 of gpg-agent is in $PATH before version 2.1.20.
uninstall version 2.0.30 of gpg-agent.

```
brew uninstall gpg-agent
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/gpg-agent/2.0.30_3... (690.2KB)
which gpg-agent
/usr/local/bin/gpg-agent
gpg-agent --version
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.1.21
```

Answer (score 3):

You could have also updated your gpg tool to a newer version, while you used also your old one. In this case, a parent-less `gpg-agent` remains in your process tree, with the already false version.

The solution is simply to kill him. Gpg will re-start it, this time a correct one.

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternate reason, that you are using some shared-home solution (for example, docker) where your multiple virtual environments see the same home directory.

Gpg starts a daemon on its first execution if it doesn't run already, and communicates with it on `~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent`. It is possible, that multiple gpg-agents from different environments see the same socket, and thus they experience incompatibility. The solution: kill the unneeded `gpg-agent` process.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** You could be using a git GUI alongside the command line both of which use their own versions of `gpg-agent`.

#### More

I also just ran into this issue. So I'll update this question with an answer from my own experience.

I use two methods of making commits to my repo.

1. I use [fork.dev](https://fork.dev) which is a Git GUI with it's own references to tools for managing git, such as `gpg-agent`.
2. I also use the command line to make commits to git. This references a different `gpg-agent` then the GUI does.

The `'gpg-agent' is older than us` warning displays under the following conditions.

1. The Git GUI has an older version of the `gpg-agent` then is used by the command line.
2. I use the Git GUI to make a commit before I use the command line.

If the GUI has an older version of `gpg-agent`, and I commit with it *first* then I will run into this issue when I try to commit via the Command Line.

Answer (score -3):

You are actually getting a warning, not an error. If you would rather not see this warning, you can pipe it away.

```
git push 2>/dev/null
```

source:  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=suppress+gpg+warnings